# Stop the onclick event listenner till all actions after one click are totally completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick, jquery-events

I have one anchor and one div. The  anchor serves for loading, via ajax, a content and appending it on a div. In fact, the whole system works for pagination. an attribute of the anchor holds the page number and is changed according to the page loaded in the div.

The problem is that multiple successive clicks on the anchor create multiples ajax calls and a disaster. How can I stop the anchor from being an onclik event listener, till one ajax call is totally performed?

Your help is appreciated.

**Edit:** 
The my onclick listener looks like:

```
$('a.left_array_trigger').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();    
        var this_this= $(this);
        var idf=parseInt($(this).attr("id"),10);
        var current= idf -2;
        var followed_id=$(this).parent().parent().attr("id");

        load_articles(followed_id,current+1);// ajax call

        $(this).attr("id",current+3);
        $(this).parent().next().next().children().attr("id",current+1);

        var maxi= current +2;
        var mini= current -2;

        $.when(get_number_of_posts(refresh_left_arrow,followed_id)).done(function(){
          if(maxi===this_number_of_pages)  this_this.css('display', 'none');
          else this_this.css('display', 'block');
        });

        if(mini!==0) $(this).parent().next().next().children().css('display', 'block' );

        return false;
   });
```

Comment: Can you post some code? It's easier to understand what you tried so far.

Comment: Are you test your code by `.removeEventListner()` ?

Comment: I think you should disable the link after click on it and enable again after append the result.

Comment: Set a variable something like var isrunning = false; on click check if it's true if not set it to true and run your code, at the end of you code reset it to false.

Comment: just use any knid of flag and reset it in ajax complete (always) callback.

Comment: @AshishMishra, thank you for your feedback. I see what you mean. I want to ask you though, what do you think about the idea of John Green answer about toggling listeners?

Comment: Thank you @PatsyIssa,  what you suggested is the solution.

Comment: @A.Wolff. Thank you, what you suggested is the solution.

Comment: @Zeeker, thank you, I have posted the code in the edit, and I think I will use a flag, and toggle it depending on the situaton.

Comment: Ya its a good idea of using flag but actually the `onclic`k is even atteched to it,if you want to remove then use `.off()` after click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With using specific data to anchor clicked:

```
$('a.left_array_trigger').click(function (e) {
    var this_this = $(this);
    if (this_this.data('unclickable')) return;
    this_this.data('unclickable', true);
    e.preventDefault();
    //...
    $.when(get_number_of_posts(refresh_left_arrow, followed_id)).done(function () {
        if (maxi === this_number_of_pages) this_this.hide();
        else this_this.show();
    }).always(function () {
        this_this.data('unclickable', false);
    });
    //...
});
```

But you should find better variable name for `this_this` as e.g `$this` or `$self`

Comment: thank you very much. I will feedback after testing your suggestions.+1

Comment: Although I normally would be totally for a data solution like this, if he's dealing pagination, he probably has multiple buttons he wants to disable at once (page+, page-, etc).  Just something for the OP to watch out for.

Comment: @JohnGreen ya, it's really depending what OP is looking for

Comment: Can I know what is OP so that I understand you? I don't know yet what to choose, a variable or data?

Comment: original poster :-) ??? If so, YEs I am using pagination as John says. I have multiple pagination buttons (about 12 on the same page).

Comment: @whitelettersandblankspaces ya, OP for original poster or sometimes opening post. ;) Here it depends if you have more than one anchor left_array_trigger or just one. If just one or more than one but still want to block anchor click for all, use global variable. If you have more than one and still want to allow user making more than one different request at a time, use data(), even data() could be used for only one anchor tag element.

Comment: @A.Wolff, I am convinced. Thank you very much for your time answering my issue (also for your suggestion regarding naming varibles and performance.)

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this, but toggling listeners can be a pain.  Just use a flag.

```
var pDiscard = false;

$('#foo').on('click', function(){
   if (pDiscard) return; // prevent multiple clicks.
   pDiscard = true; // temporarily ignore.
   $.ajax('/foo/bar/').always(function(){
      pDiscard = false; // unignore.
   });
});
```

Comment: +1, thank you, I understand your solution, I will feedback after implementing it and all the other suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid a variable you can do the following:

```
$('#foo').on('click', function(){

   // The anchor is locked, return
   if ($(this).data('locked')) 
      return;

   // Let's lock the anchor
   $(this).data('locked', true);

   $.ajax('/foo/bar/').always($.proxy(function(){

      // Unlock the anchor
      $(this).removeData('locked');

      // Do whatever you need to do here <3

   }, this));
});
```

Comment: +1, I understand the difference. What is about performance? is using variable lightweight than `.data()` and `.removeData()`?

Comment: You shouldn't worry here about performance, the difference would be count in nano seconds, nothing you'll never notice.